# $G$-Force on falling object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, acceleration, free-fall

I'm trying to understand how G-Force is calculated, specifically with drop tests but also generally.

If an object is sitting on a table it has a G-Force of 1. i.e. it has 9.81m/s^2 of acceleration applied to it, due to gravity.

If the object is dropped from a height with no added force, the object falls at a constant rate (9.81) until it makes contact with the ground - here is where things change, the acceleration is now 0?

But the accelerometer is saying higher values of Gs. How is the acceleration being multiplied by higher numbers here?

Comment: What is your implementation? Sounds like you aren't reading raw accelerometer readings but took someone else's code you don't understand and used it. People like to apply offsets to their code so that it outputs acceleration of the entire sensor in Earth gravity rather than what force is being measuring between its beam and frame, or capture-hold max readings. Also raw accelerometers measure zero in free fall even though they are accelerating at 1g due to the beam-frame thing.

Comment: This isn't in relation to coding, just talking physics in general.

Comment: I'm asking whether you understand the equipment you are using because your post is contradictory or unclear what is a real measurement you are getting and what is a thought experiment/your understanding.

Comment: Please allow me to clarify for you; How is G Force calculated on a body when making impact and does G-Force remain constant until the point of impact?

Comment: Just edit into your post whenever you are talking about a measurement you are getting and when you are talking about your understanding of how it should be. Because they can be pretty opposite from how we like to think of things as an observer outside the sensor versus what is being measured due to how accelerometers work. Raw accelerometers *measure* zero in free fall and 1G on a table but you say the opposite.

Comment: But if your last comment is your question you need to know material deformation since that determines the distance over which the sensor is being decelerated on impact. I guess you could say the kinetic energy is used to do work against itself to produce the decelerate force.

Answer (score 0):

When making impact with the ground an object undergoes a large deceleration.

During impact the $G$ force is worked out as change in speed divided by change in time
$$\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t}$$

Then divide by $9.81$

After the object has hit the floor the $G$ force is $1$ (if it's now resting on the floor) and before impact the $G$ force is also zero (in the sense that it is weightless during the fall) -  but the higher numbers are for when it's in the process of being stopped, i.e. during the actual impact with the floor.

---

It's really concerned with the compressive force acting on the object.  So when falling, the object isn't being compressed and the $G$ force is zero.  When resting on a table, the $G$ force is $1$ even though there doesn't seem to be any acceleration  - that's because the normal contact force is acting on one side, and the object will be compressed in a similar way to an object being pushed from one side with an acceleration of $9.81$m/s$^2$.